# aplicar regex en un csv

Tags: python, regex, csv

Estoy intentando leer un fichero `csv`, al hacer eso instanció el parámetro de expresiones regulares para que traten el fichero y luego exportarlo transformado, pero no sucede nada cuando lo ejecuto. ¿En que estoy fallando?

```py
import re
import csv

def urlify(s):

    # Eliminar caracteres especiales
    s = re.sub(r'[œâ  Ø]', ' ', s)

    # Eliminar todos los caracteres que no sean palabras (Excepto números y letras)
    s = re.sub(r'[^\w\sa-zA-Z0-9 \n\.]', ' ', s)

    # Reemplazar los caracteres (No necesarios) por espacios en blanco
    s = re.sub(r'\s', ' ', s)

    return s

file = open('PruebasP.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
final_data = [[re.sub(s) for b in i] for i in csv.reader(file)]

file = open('PruebasP.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
write = csv.writer(file)

write.writerows(final_data)
```

No sé si es correcto el llamando que hago en `final_data`.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Para aclararme, ¿quieres aplicar las substituciones celda  a celda verdad?

Comment: No necesariamente, podría tambien aplicar las 3 expresiones regulares en la misma ínea pero no consigo hacerlo funcionar. la finalidad es que esas 3 expresiones regulares traten mi csv y  se sobreescriba transformado.

Comment: Hacerlo linea a linea o incluso procesar el fichero entero podría ser más eficiente, pero tenemos el problema de los acotados,separadores, etc y no es difícil terminar con un csv inválido. Otra duda, quieres eliminar en las dos primeras expresiones según e comentario, pero estás sustituyendo por un espacio en blanco ¿es un typo o solo que el comentario debería ser como el de la tercera?

Comment: Correcto, primeramente elimino en las  2  primeras lineas los caracteres no necesarios y los  caracteres especiales manteniendo su espacio. Las  3 primeras lineas funciona perfectamente porque si yo le paso un string para probarlo es decir: ```print(urllify("1344Ø      —   002790200514170649301200514703  œâ  Ø "))``` me imprime el string limpio manteniendo los espacios. Me dejo entender? . Solo que esos strings estan en un CSV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes llamar a la función por cada celda del archivo CSV, además, recuerda que siempre debe cerrarse un fichero abierto cuando se termina con él, explícitamente o mejor usando `with` y el administrador de contexto:

```py
import re
import csv

def urlify(s):

    # Eliminar caracteres especiales
    s = re.sub(r'[œâ  Ø]', ' ', s)

    # Eliminar todos los caracteres que no sean palabras (excepto números y letras)
    s = re.sub(r'[^\w\sa-zA-Z0-9 \n\.]', ' ', s)

    # Reemplazar los caracteres (No necesarios) por espacios en blanco
    s = re.sub(r'\s', ' ', s)

    return s

with open('PruebasP.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    final_data = [[urlify(str(col)) for col in line] for line in csv.reader(file)]

with open('PruebasP.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    csv.writer(file).writerows(final_data)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, se te agradece!